# How to generate multiple Ethereum addresses from a seed phrase with Web3 and Eth Account and match them with Metamask?

Tags: python, metamask

I am trying to use Python to generate multiple Ethereum addresses from a single seed phrase that I have in my Metamask wallet. I was able to generate a single address that matches my first account in Metamask using the following code:

```
from web3 import Web3
from eth_account import Account

# Connect to Metamask's local RPC server
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

# Enable the use of the Mnemonic features
Account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()

# Set the seed phrase
seed_phrase = 'my seed phrase'

# Create an account from the seed phrase
account = web3.eth.account.from_mnemonic(seed_phrase)

# Print the account's address
print(account.address)
```

However, when I tried to generate multiple addresses using different code snippets, none of them produced addresses that matched the ones in my Metamask wallet. I am unsure of what I need to do to generate the correct addresses. Please help me